# Why do we need this site when Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User exist?

Tags: discussion

What value does this site add?

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint Overflow is:

- Solely about SharePoint and all of its parts (end-user, infrastructure, development, ...). This makes it a very convenient central location to visit rather than hopping between several sites.
- Promoted by the SharePoint Pod Show. This gives the site a targeted audience that come to ask and answer SharePoint questions.
- Running on a related but different platform to the Stack Overflow family of sites called Stack Exchange. This allows us to develop the site with features most appropriate for SharePoint users.
- Operated by people with great experience within the SharePoint community and run to support the interests of **all of us** in the SharePoint world!